# Returning JSON through angular and bible.org api or esvapi.org

Tags: json, angularjs, api, asp.net-web-api

I've been researching this and cannot find or understand some of the solutions so i'm hoping to get some help here. I'm using Asp.net and building an application that needs to use a bible api. I like the two listed in the question. Every time I call esvapi it comes back successful, but I cannot view the data. I get an error in the console.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.esvapi.org/v2/rest`/passageQuery?key=8834092f0c58fcda&passage=James2. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:59324' is therefore not allowed access.`
```

I've seen other with this error and I have questions.

1. If I'm understanding this correct I get this because the server is preventing me from seeing the data for security purposes. Maybe even the browser( this is not just a chrome issue) problem. So if I need to add a info to the response header from Angularjs to stop this how is that done. Anyone with experience?
2. Would I need to contact anyone to be able to prevent the server from responding this way...I doubt this, but thought I would ask. I already have valid api key.
3. the bible.org website api key is confusing to apply to my code. on esvapi i just add a header with key: "keypass" and I only have the CORS issue. But with bible.org I can't figure out how to implement the api key and password. see below... Do I say token:key: username. If i put the api in the browser I get a popup to add username and password. the username is my key and the password is ignored. I tried putting in username as key, but that didn't cut it. Regardless I need to fix the CORS issue and add info to response headers to see response data.

   ```
   $scope.search = function() {
       return $http.get("http://www.esvapi.org/v2/rest/passageQuery?&passage=" + $scope.bo + $scope.chap, {
           headers: {
               "key?token?orusername?": "",
               ///thought i saw someone do this...don't know if this is right
               "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "Content-Disposition",
           }
       }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           $scope.book = data.Book;
           $scope.chapter = data.Chapter;
           $scope.output = data.Output;
       }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           $scope.message = "Oops... something went wrong";

       });
   ```

Any input would be helpful. Thanks!

I actually have a bible api working...just a version that I don't like and there is not another version on that webites api.

Answer (score 1):

Change the get $http.get call to $http.jsonp and hope it works. You're using cross-site scripting. Sometimes you can get away with a JSONP call in these cases and sometimes you can't.